# Keep them spread out?

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, collision

Sorry if the title is ambiguous, I don't know how to really word what I'm trying to do.

So, anyway, I've created a basic zombie game where green squares follow you, you can die and kill the zombies.

The problem is, if there's a large crowd of the zombies, they all go into eachother and make one square, seeing as collision is too hard to do since they're moving along where they're pointing (pointing at the player), is there a way I can keep them spread out enough so they never go into eachother?

here's the code where I move the zombies:

```
        for (var i2:int; i2 < ZombiesOnScreen.length; i2++ )
        {
            if (ZombiesOnScreen[i2].alive == true)
            {
                var dist_Y2:Number = player.y - ZombiesOnScreen[i2].y;
                var dist_X2:Number = player.x - ZombiesOnScreen[i2].x;
                var angle2:Number = Math.atan2(dist_Y2, dist_X2);
                var degrees2:Number = angle2 * 180 / Math.PI;
                ZombiesOnScreen[i2].rotation = degrees2;
                var zomBAngle:Number = ZombiesOnScreen[i2].rotation * Math.PI / 180;
                ZombiesOnScreen[i2].x = ZombiesOnScreen[i2].x + 1.6 * Math.cos(zomBAngle);
                ZombiesOnScreen[i2].y = ZombiesOnScreen[i2].y + 1.6 * Math.sin(zomBAngle);
            }
            if (ZombiesOnScreen[i2].hitTestObject(player))
            {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
```

Also, sorry if this is literally just collision but just spaced out, I just want a way to stop them merging.

Answer (score 0):

It may be beyond your current programming level but one common approach to this is on based the work of [Craig Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids), outlined in his paper entitled "Flocks, herds and schools: A distributed behavioral model". He later released the C++ lib "[openSteer](http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/)." See his paper [Steering Behaviors For Autonomous Characters](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/) for Java applet examples and a simplified explanation.

There have been many actionscript implementations of [flocking behavior and ports of openSteer](https://www.google.com/search?q=Flocking%20actionscript&gbv=1&sei=jAOtVqfVIIK5-QHvt7_4BA). Be careful though – you can't just copy and paste the code.